# PHP - getting the value from the multidimensional array using another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
$mainArray = array(
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'test'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'news'],
        ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'foo'],
        ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'bar']...
        );

$array = array(1,2,5,6,7);
```

I need to check if the id from the **$mainArray** is contained in the **$array**, and if it is contained it needs to print the name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(With this solution you have an array with the `id` as `key` and the `name` as `value`)

```
<?php

    $mainArray = array(
                    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'test'],
                    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'news'],
                    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'foo'],
                    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'bar']
                );

    $array = array(1,2,5,6,7);
    $result = array();

    foreach($mainArray as $k => $v)
        $result[$v["id"]] = (array_intersect($mainArray[$k], $array) ? $mainArray[$k]["name"] : "");

    $result = array_filter($result);
    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [1] => test [2] => news )
```

And you can easy go through the array an print every thing like this:

```
array_walk($result, function($value, $key) { 
    echo "Key: $key Value: $value <br />";
});

//OR

foreach($result as $key => $value)
    echo "Key: $key Value: $value <br />";
```

Output:

```
Key: 1 Value: test 
Key: 2 Value: news
```

Comment: While this does work, it does seem a little convoluted and prone to false positives. First, you are adding every id to the `$result` array and then removing them later, why not just check and add only the ones that match? And second using array_intersect will check all vals in the sub array. If there was another column that had a value that matched one of the ids found in `$array`, for example if a `count` was added that had a count of times the `name` existed in another table, it would create a false positive. Also, using array_intersect will check all values when only 1 needs to be checked.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I think you can write this in like 5 different ways at least and all would work! So i don't wanted to post the same solution as Zach Spencer did, i wanted to show another way! And you're compeletly right, but it's every time a question what OP needs.

Comment: I understand, but while it is a valid way, it technically isn't the correct way because this will only cause more problems later on when making changes to the code.

Answer (score 3):

simple!

```
foreach($mainArray as $arr) {
    if(in_array($arr['id'], $array)) {
        echo $arr['id'];
    }
}
```